# Find every quadruple which sum to a given value

Tags: algorithm, math, complexity-theory

I know this topic is like 20 times shown here. But, every question does not fit my answer.

I want to find every quadruple (4 numbers) bigger or equal to 0 (natural number), that sum up to a given value. Those quadruples can be repeating.

For Example:

```
Wanted sum: 1
Possible quadruples:
    0 0 0 1
    0 0 1 0
    0 1 0 0
    1 0 0 0
```

I want to get those quadruple as an output. Note that there is no given Array of numbers (all Natural Numbers are possible).

I know you can get this by bruteforce, but I want the most efficient way.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Theorem 2 is totally the problem thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i <= sum; i++)
  for(int j = 0; j <= sum - i; j++)
    for(int k = 0; k <= sum - i - j; k++)
      output(i, j, k, sum - i - j - k);
```